# pyqt what's different QWidget(self) vs QWidget(class name)

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm little confusing meaning of widgets instance creation in PyQt.

Seems QWidget(self) can create a widget.
But what's the meaning of QWidget(instance name)?

For exmaple,

```
grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)
test_label = QWidget(grid_layout)
```

I know test_label created inherited from gridlayout.
But what's the meaning during program meaning?
Is that meaning test_label widget is under grid_layout?

Comment: There are many issues in your question: 1. no widget accepts a "class name" as argument; 2. the Qt parent/child relation (which is based on instances) has nothing to do with inheritance (which class-related); 3. `gridlayout` is an instance, not a class; 4. there's conceptually no difference between using `self` or any other QWidget reference, since in the case above `self` clearly refers to a QWidget; 5. widgets only accept other QWidget subclasses as parents, QGridLayout does not inherit from QWidget so the second line above will raise an exception. I believe you're making some confusion: ->

Comment: -> you're probably mistaking with `class QWidget(SomeWidgetClass):`, which is a *completely* different thing, as that is a class definition, not an instance constructor. I strongly suggest you to do some more research on what classes/instances are and how they work (including inheritance), what is the meaning of `self`, and how the parent/child relation works under Qt, how it affects widgets and other objects, and their lifespan during program execution.

Comment: @musicamante I missed instance name as class name.

Comment: @HyunYoungGo There's no difference at all. The only thing that matters is the *type* of the argument, which must be a subclass of QWidget (or `None`). Your example will therefore raise a TypeError, since QGridLayout does not inherit QWidget. When the correct argument is passed, it sets the [parent-widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#parentWidget) of the widget (see also [the Qt docs for the QWidget constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWidget)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many of the widgets when the signature is just a single parameter like in both of your examples, the argument given sets the created widget/layouts parent.

So in your first example, using `self` as the argument means that the parent of the QGridLayout and the widget that the layout will be applied to is whatever widget `self` is.

In the second example you are setting the parent of QWidget to be the widget represented by it's argument.  A QWidget with no parent becomes a new window, when set with a parent then the widget becomes a child window within the parent widget.

Neither one are inheriting anything.  Inheritance only occurs during Subclassing.

Comment: The C++ origin is irrelevant, that argument usage could work with pure Python objects, nor the parent/child relationship is strictly related to the constructor signature, as it completely depends on the logic of the objects and how their classes work.

Comment: That choice is only by design, Qt developers choose that common, internal "standard", for which any signature of QObject constructors always has the (often optional) parent as last. But, as said, the C++ origin is irrelevant, as that can also be achieved in a similar fashion with Python, using packed positional arguments (`*args`). Note that the OP also used an invalid argument for the second case, as QWidgets can only accept a QWidget subclass as parent, while QGridLayout does not inherit from QWidget.